# Get the AUTO_INCREMENT value after inserting a new row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, row, auto-increment

How can I get the `id` that was just inserted for the current user if it is controlled by `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

(I need the Id for another use)

Note: some row can be deleted so `MAX(id)` is not an option.

Ex:

inserted row 2

inserted row 3

deleted row 3

inserted row 4 but `MAX(id)` returns 3..

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have tagged this question [tag:php]: which API are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PDO:

```
$db->lastInsertId(); // $db is the PDO object
```

With MySQLi OOP:

```
$db->insert_id; // $db is the MySQLi object
```

With MySQLi procedural:

```
mysqli_insert_id($db); // $db is the connection variable
```

If you're using the old MySQL API, switch.

Comment: I dont understand how to use it.. mysql_insert_id returns int and its just goes into a variable. but mysqli_insert_id returns mixed and I have no idea how to use it..

Comment: Are you using the new MySQLi API, or the old MySQL one? You're probably using the latter, since `mysql_insert_id` returns an integer (which is what its supposed to).

Comment: You should know that the old `mysql_*` API is deprecated since PHP 5.5, and is less secure. You should really upgrade to MySQLi.

Comment: yup I use `mysql_insert_id` and it works. Can you help me upgrade my code to mysqli?

Comment: lets do that in chat if you'd like @Marcel

Comment: You should learn the API and change YOUR code YOURSELF. I don't do this for free. Here's something to get you started off: http://codular.com/php-mysqli/, and of course: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php.

Answer (score 0):

try

select @@identity

This should return the last value in the identity column

Answer (score 0):

Since your answer is tagged with PHP, I'll answer in that context. If you're using the PDO API, you can use [PDO::lastInsertId](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). If you're using the mysql function API, the equivalent would be [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

Edit: Ninja'd :P

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql_insert_id() or mysqli_insert_id()

Comment: I dont understand how to use it.. mysql_insert_id returns int and its just goes into a variable. but mysqli_insert_id returns mixed and I have no idea how to use it..

Comment: For mysqli_insert_id you are required to pass connection variable to the function. Like mysqli_insert_id($con); You can also use LAST_INSERT_ID() for the same.

Answer (score -1):

you can use **[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

**EDIT:**

**mysql_insert_id** is deprecated. now its [mysqli_insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Don't use it.

Comment: I dont understand how to use it.. `mysql_insert_id` returns int and its just goes into a variable. but `mysqli_insert_id` returns `mixed` and I have no idea how to use it..